# E-mail sending code executed for 100 participants only

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, limit

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = 'EMAIL_SENT';

/**
 * Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 7; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 3);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2]; // Third column
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = 'Delivering your ID for R2U 2021';
      GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
```

}
1:56:00 PM  Notice  Execution started
1:56:01 PM  Error
Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: email.
sendEmails2 @ Code.gs:23

Why does this error appear and is there a way to fix this?

Comment: [You can review the limits here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) -- taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068737/google-apps-script-service-invoked-too-many-times-for-one-day-email)

Comment: As you can probably guess, you can fix it by paying money.